Django Deploy Nginx Bad Gateway no such file or directory
So, I've been struggling for the past week to deploy my Django project on my VPS server (domains.co.za). After all this time, I managed to figure out a few things on my own. My server runs on AlmaLinux 9, and I'm connecting via the IP address 41.76.110.165. Here's what I've done so far:
Gunicorn Configuration (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service)
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=marco
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/marco/domestic_voicelogging
ExecStart=/home/marco/domestic_voicelogging/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          domestic_voicelogging.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Gunicorn Socket (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket)
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock
SocketUser=marco
SocketGroup=www-data
SocketMode=0660

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

Nginx Configuration (/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject)
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 41.76.110.165;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/marco/domestic_voicelogging;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}

I'm encountering this error:

2024/07/09 10:11:40 [crit] 21042#21042: *8 connect() to unix:/opt/domestic_voicelogging.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 41.13.200.12, server: mydjangoserver.co.za, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/opt/domestic_voicelogging.sock:/", host: "41.76.110.165"

Current Socket Status
(venv) [marco@mydjangoserver domestic_voicelogging]$ ls -l /run/gunicorn.sock
srw-rw-rw-. 1 marco www-data 0 Jul 9 09:37 /run/gunicorn.sock
(venv) [marco@mydjangoserver domestic_voicelogging]$

I'm puzzled why the directory path in the error message shows /opt/domestic_voicelogging.sock instead of /run/gunicorn.sock. I've checked everything seems correct, yet I'm still unable to access my site via IP, receiving a "502 Bad Gateway" error.
Could someone please assist with troubleshooting this issue?
